# How to extract text until it reaches a capital word? Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

This is my complete text:

```
RETENTION
Liability in excess of the Retention
The Retention shall be borne by the Named Insured and the Insurer shall only be liable for Loss once the Retention has been fully eroded. The Retention shall apply until such time as it has been fully eroded after which no Retention shall apply.
Erosion of the Retention
The Retention shall be eroded by Loss for which the Insurer would be liable under this Policy but for the Retention.
```

I want to extract the whole RETENTION paragraph.

This was my code to extract the sentences which have a specific word (here: Retention).

```
abc3=([sentence + '.' for sentence in txt_trim_string.split('.') if 'RETENTION' in sentence])
```

But this gave the output as:

```
RETENTION
Liability in excess of the Retention
The Retention shall be borne by the Named Insured and the Insurer shall only be liable for Loss once the Retention has been fully eroded.
```

I also want to include:

```
Erosion of the Retention
The Retention shall be eroded by Loss for which the Insurer would be liable under this Policy but for the Retention.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you define the pattern here? What are the boundaries of a paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do everything BUT a full capital word. To get a fully capitalized word, you can use the following regex: `([A-Z]){2,}`

That expression captures words that have 2 or more capital letters next to each other.

---

Another way to go about it is to use the following regex: `[A-Z]?([^A-Z])` This selects 0 or 1 capital letters followed by anything that isn't two capital letters next to each other.

```
import re
regex = r'[A-Z]?([^A-Z])'
for result in regex.findall(<your text as a string>):
    print(result[1:]) # there will be an extraneous character when a fully capitalized word is encountered
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `[A-Z]{2,}.*?(?=(?:[A-Z]{2,}|\Z))` with `re.DOTALL` option to match newline with `.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Xgv1R/1/)